# Forms background re-sizing?

Tags: c#, forms, background, resize

i was wondering if there is anyway to Re-size a Forms background Image according to how high and how wide the form is. A property or a code maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set
`BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;`

in either the Code or the Forms editor.